# FTP file importing issue

Tags: ftp, data-importer

I am trying to make a ftp importer , its almost done , but to optimize it further I would like to see whether the requested file has been updated in the server or not.
If its already present and not been modified I won't fetch it again. What would be the best approach for it. please help